# How do I build Google Crashpad with MSVC (Microsoft Visual C++) 2015?

Tags: visual-c++, chromium, google-breakpad, visual-c++-2015

Google Crashpad claims to compile with MSVC 2015 and MSVC 2017 (at the time of writing this post).

However, Google Crashpad depends on [mini_chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/mini_chromium/), which is a chromium project that [explicitly indicates MSVC 2017 or greater is required](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/windows_build_instructions.md).

I've tried compiling Crashpad following [this guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/HEAD/doc/developing.md), and the most up-to-date Crashpad commits, and [depot_tools](https://dev.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/depottools). I can successfully compile on MSVC 2017, but receive a considerable number of compiler errors with MSVC 2015 and mini_chromium - and I need my client software to dynamically link against libraries compiled using MSVC 2015.

[This StackOverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57486462/how-do-i-build-google-crashpad-into-shared-dynamic-libraries/57531810#57531810) enabled me to build Crashpad into dynamic libraries. But I can only do so in MSVC 2017. When I later try to link MSVC 2015 compiled software against Crashpad build in MSVC 2017, I get [this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50879346/what-does-ot-flag-stand-for-in-visual-studio-2017).

Answer (score 3):

I successfully compiled Crashpad with MSVC 2015.

This required me to dig up old commits (prior to Crashpad utilizing mini_chromium aspects that only compiled with MSVC 2017).

The process I followed is as follows:

1. Follow [this guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/crashpad/crashpad/+/HEAD/doc/developing.md) for first setting up Google Crashpad
2. After following the above guide, and getting depot_tools cloned (and in your PATH), go into your depot_tools directory and pull an old commit (just prior to May 1, 2018):

> `$ cd ~/depot_tools/`
>
> ```
> git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --first-parent --before="2018-05-01" master`
> ```

3. Do the same thing for your crashpad repository:

> `$ cd ~/crashpad/crashpad`
>
> ```
> git checkout `git rev-list -n 1 --first-parent --before="2018-05-01" master`
> ```

4. In your crashpad repo, use **gclient** to synchronize your dependencies (following [this guide](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/building_old_revisions.md))

> `$ gclient sync -D --force --reset`

You should now be free to compile Crashpad with MSVC 2015 normally:

> `cd ~/crashpad/crashpad`
>
> `gn gen out/Default`
>
> `ninja -C out/Default`